# What are the exact bounds of the scroll-to-top gesture tapping area?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uiscrollview

When using the scroll-to-top gesture (see [[UIScrollView scrollsToTop]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollsToTop)) as a user, I find it difficult to hit the correct area for generating this gesture. On my test device, an IPhone 4S, this area seems to occupy a very thin part of the top of my application area plus only the bottom of the status bar, which still, even when combined, leaves it a rather thin, hard to hit area.

- What are the exact bounds of this area?
- Can it be configured programmatically to make it easier to use this gesture, e.g. most obviously to make the tapping area bigger?

Given the fact that Apple has design guides which specify how touchable objects have to look and what minimum size tapping areas have to cover, it seems that this feature does not even comply with Apple's own rules for user interfaces. I presume that there have been discussions about this feature in the regard that it is difficult to discover in the first place, and that it is difficult to use in the second place. Having any references to such discussions or any other insight on this topic would be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

scrollsToTop works on scrollview when we touch the status bar, and there are not other scrollviews in with scrollsToTop property value YES. There should be only one scrollview in the view hierarchy having this value to be YES.
So the touchable rect would be the frame of the status bar. And if you want to capture this event then you have to use custom overlay of the status bar for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's difficult to touch status bar. One workaround is to add a status bar overlay. Make the overlay view larger may help.

1. To add a custom view to the top of `UIWindow`.
2. Register an `UITapGestureRecognizer`.
3. Handle tap action. e.g. scroll the scroll view to top.

A few things you should be ware of:

1. Rotation
2. Auto resizing
3. Underneath touch event. Your overlay might block navigation button items' touch event, so do a `hitTest` in your overlay view to make sure the user can touch though the button areas.

BTW: Few users know that they could tap the status bar to make the scroll view scroll to top. A little frustrating tough. ;)